# ¿Cómo dar formato a fecha día(numérico) y mes(letras?)

Tags: java, date

**A ver yo tengo esto**

```
           yyyMMdd   20180705
```

**y quiero esto:**

```
          05 
          Jul
```

**Actualizo**

Osea necesito por un lado solo el dia en numero y por  otro lado el principio del mes en letras. Es decir, el dia en una variable y el mes en otra
Por cierto, la fecha la tengo en String ya que la recupero de la base en un Json, intuyo que primero tendré que pasarla a Date.

muchas gracias

**Actualizo 2: tengo esto**

```
    String recoveryDate;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date fecha = null;

    try {
        fecha = originalFormat.parse(recoveryDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String finalDate = targetFormat.format(fecha);
```

aqui ya tengo la fecha en Date, pero no se seguir para obtener el comienzo del mes en letras.

Comment: y que has probado o investigado? Dinos lo que has intentado, hasta donde has llegado y donde te ha fallado y así podremos echarte una mano

Comment: Conviene que indiques tu intento de código y qué error tienes... Y que eventualmente aclares sobre este valor `yyyMMdd   20180705` ¿lo tienes así tal cual, con **tres espacios** entre ambos valores, o son dos valores distintos del JSON?

Comment: no, el string que yo recupero es 20180705,  lo de yyyMMdd era el ejemplo.
el String lo paso a Date  luego no se como conseguir el mes en letras

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: gracias  voy a mirar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución posible sería convertir el String recibido a date, y al mostrarlo, convertirlo a String

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String fechaRecibida = "20180705";

    Date fechaConcreta = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(fechaRecibida);

    String fechaNueva = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM").format(fechaConcreta);

    System.out.println(fechaNueva);
}
```

La consola muestra esto:

05 julio